# Best DB method for Android app?

Tags: android, database, web-services

I'm looking to build a simple app that streams midi files to a user. The database I want to use has to be remote, as I plan to have many files and to avoid having a large 100mb+ app I prefer to just stream the small midi files when the user requests them.

I'm not sure which database method to use or what is easiest and best to use. I know SQLite works with android but as I said I plan for the DB to be remote. What is the best method for the DB and web service?

Comment: So you just need a suitable database for your webservice backend?  MySQL and PostgreSQL are the obvious (and free) choices, with the former probably being easier to get started with.

Comment: Okay. thank you for the information. I'll take a look at this, databases are rather new for me so this is all very confusing sadly. Thanks again.

Comment: @SystemIsGod And so your aware, with most applications, you have a back-end database (what Argyle posted above) then your app will query the information (via some web interface/script), then store it within its SQLite database.

Comment: @Ancantus, what do you mean? I'm sorry, you mean I would have a database on the device as well as the server? All I would like it to do is display the information and then stream the music if the user selected "play."

Comment: @SystemIsGod It depends on your app, but chances are good that you'll need to store *some* data on the client, and SQLite is the obvious choice for that.  If you just have simple name/value pairs you can get away with using Android's `SharedPreferences`, though.

Comment: @SystemIsGod Sorry to confuse. You don't have to have a database on the device if you don't need it. Just kinda explaining how you would get the data from the remote server to the device (what you do with the data is all up to you).